# Openoffice error Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, openoffice.org

I just installed openoffice. I can open it from terminal by typing "soffice", but I can't seem to open it with the gui. There are the openoffice icons there but when I click on them they open, run, then closes but does not show the main software.

Comment: I'm just asking so we know whether that's actually your problem. Do you know that OpenOffice is pretty much dead and Ubuntu comes with LibreOffice by default? If you removed LibreOffice in the past, you can just reinstall it by typing in `sudo apt install libreoffice`.

Comment: My problem is genuine.

Comment: I use Ubuntu MATE, not regular Ubuntu (with Unity), so forgive my ignorance -- but is there a way to right-click on the icon to see what command it runs when you click on it? To see what *specific* command it's trying to launch? For example, if it's trying to run `/usr/bin/soffice-writer`, you could try typing that in a terminal to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: @NickWeinberg there is a way, might not be to right click but for sure you can check the `/usr/share/applications/*.desktop` file to find out exactly what command is run and what parameters are passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Nautilus and navigate to `/usr/share/applications`. Find the started for OpenOffice. Then copy the file and paste it into the folder `~/.local/share/applications`.

Note that `~` is your home folder and files/folders whose names start with `.` are hidden by default and you can press `ctrl + H` in Nautilus to make them visible.

Then open GEdit and drag the file you just pasted into it. Search for the line which starts with `Exec=` and change that line to `Exec=soffice` because you said that executing `soffice` works for you. Save the file.

Right-click the file you pasted into `~/.local/share/applications` and choose `Properties`. Switch to the `Permissions` tab and check the checkbox which says "Allow executing file as program".

You can double-click the file to find out whether it works. If it works if you double-click the file but doesn't work from the dash instantly, logging out and in again or restarting the computer is probably the easiest solution.

Note that this only works for users with the adapted starter in `~/.local/share/applications`. If several people use the computer and you want it to work for all of them, you have to make the change in the file you found in `/usr/share/applications` which requires root rights. If there only is one account or only one account you want to use OpenOffice with, choose the solution I described above.